# we want the navbar.php only the file scrollable when Active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

While working on our navigation bar in a file named navbar.php, we aim to create a scenario where only the content within navbar.php is scrollable when the .hamburger is active, while the rest of the elements remain static. How can we achieve this?

The issue is that the files, such as navbar.php containing the navigation bar, and home.php with the dashboard, are separate from each other. Despite not using the 'include' function, these files collectively form a single webpage.

Here's the rest of the code from navbar.php:

```
`  
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

body {
    z-index: 4;
}

header {
    background: white;
    width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

header nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header nav ul li a {
    color: black;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}

.hamburger {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 10px;
    left: 5px;
}

.hamburger div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    background: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .hamburger {
        display: block;
    }

    header nav {
        position: absolute;
        left: -100%;
        width: 220px;
        top: 10px;
        background: white;
        padding: 5px;
        transition: 0.3s;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    header #nav_check:checked ~ nav {
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    input:checked~.hamburger {
        left: 180px;
        transition: 0.3s ease;
        z-index: 4;
    }

    header nav ul  {
        display: block;
    }

    header nav ul li a {
        margin: 5px 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
}

.collapse a {
    text-indent: 10px;
    color: lightpink;
}

nav#sidebar {
    /* <?php echo $_SESSION['system']['cover_img'] ?>) */ 
}

#sidebarToggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
    color: purple;
}

nav#sidebar {
    height: calc(100%);
    z-index: 3;
    width: 220px;
    font-size: 13px;
    top: 35px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

a.nav-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
    background-color: #ffffffc4;
    color: #adb5bd;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.nav-item.active, .nav-item.active:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #F089e5, #F56387);
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.3s ease;
}

a.nav-item:hover {
    color: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #F089e5, #F56387);
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
</style>

<header>
<input type="checkbox" id="nav_check" hidden>
<nav id="sidebar" class='mx-lt-5 bg-pink active'>
    <div class="scrollable-content">
        <ul>
            <center><img src="assets/uploads/loader.png"></center>
            <!-- Your list items go here -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<label for="nav_check" class="hamburger">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
 </label>
</header>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebarToggle').click(function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });

    $('.nav_collapse').click(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('href'))
        $($(this).attr('href')).collapse()
    });
    $('.nav-<?php echo isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '' ?>').addClass('active');
});
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sidebarToggle').click(function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });

    $('.nav_collapse').click(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('href'))
        $($(this).attr('href')).collapse()
    });
    $('.nav-<?php echo isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '' ?>').addClass('active');
});
</script>
```

`

We would like it so that when the navbar is active, the home.php or other files where not scrollable at all. Help is highly appreciated. We are new so we don't really know what we are doing.

Comment: How is this problem related to PHP or CSS? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: _"Despite not using the 'include' function, these files collectively form a single webpage."_ - so how exactly then, if you do _not_ use include/require on the server side? And why are you embedding jQuery _twice_, and also have it followed by what appear to be identicial script blocks each time?

Comment: _"We would like it so that when the navbar is active, the home.php or other files where not scrollable at all."_ - you don't "scroll files", you scroll the web page shown in your browser - or parts thereof. But _where_ in your page the content of the home.php is actually getting embedded, is currently unclear.